# How to pause consumers from consuming messages in spring cloud kinesis stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I am looking at a solution to pause the consumption of messages from a kinesis stream from the app itself when the down stream service is down. I am using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis. There is no obvious option to do that. There doesn't seem to be an option on KCL api as well.There is stop/pause on spring actuator bindings end point which doesn't seem to work for Kinesis. One option is to use AWS SDK api and do a pull rather than the push mechanism of KCL/Spring cloud and stop pulling on a circuit breaker.

Are there any other options to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinesis consumers (independently of library) don't support `pause/resume` at all. There is just no such a concept in AWS Kinesis.

You indeed can use `start/stop` actuator endpoints for particular binding to control its lifecycle.

Not sure why do you say it doesn't work: there is no difference with other binders in this part.

Comment: In the response from actuator/bindings pausable is false. That could be the reason why it is not pausing. Not sure how to make pausable true though.

Comment: One more time: you can't `pause` Kinesis consumer - there is no such a functionality. That's why it is always `false` for that call. You have to use `stop/start` instead.

Comment: By injecting the BindingdEndpoint class that the actuator uses I have managed to stop and start the consumption of the stream programatically.

Comment: To add more about using actuator to start , stop binders, it works fine with one shard on the stream and 2 consumers. But doesn't work with two shards  and two consumers. In case of two shards and two consumers once we start/stop binders the consumption becomes unpredictable with a shard never getting consumed. Test done is, Stream with 2 shards and two consumers A and B. works fine first when both A and B up with the first one consuming both shards. Stop A, B works fine. Stop B  then start A in this case records on one of the shards never get consumed until restart.